# how to setup multiple filter in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I read QA in stackoverflow, but not described about how to setup controlled single and multiple in same time,

i have a multiple filter, but sometime use can select only one or more, when we come to our react form

```
  handleChange = (e) => {

    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name  = target.name;
    this.setState({[name]:value})
    this.props.onChange({[name]:value})
  }

..................

carPrice: 
<input 
name="carPrice" 
type="text"  
value={this.state.carPrice} 
onChange={this.handleChange}/> 

price_category : 
<select 
name="price_category" 
value={this.state.price_category} 
onChange={this.handleChange} >
    <option >Select</option>
    <option value="low">Low</option>
    <option value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="high">High</option>
</select>
```

Here is the form, user can select one or more filter same time.
the output looks like when user give input

```
{price_category: "low"}
```

if give car Price

```
{ carPrice: "20000"}
```

**Filter here**

Here we are filter the sate,

```
f = (filterparams)=>{

    //filterparams ---> {price_category: "low"} 

    let filtercars = this.state.cars // car array here


    filtercars = filtercars.filter
    (
        car=> {return car.carPrice <= filterparams.carPrice || 
        car.price_category === filterparams.price_category }
    )

      this.setState({
        filtercars
    })
  }
```

**Issue**

- selecting *car rate* 5000, its show car under the price = work fine
- then selecting price category **high**, shows car under 5000 and **high** = work fine
- then selecting car rate 1000, shows all cars from *price category* **high** =  not working

---

**Edit**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CarResult cars={this.state.filtercars} onChange={this.f}/>
      </div>
    )
      }
```

Comment: Please be specific. Include the code where you think problem lies. At least where `f(filterparams)` is used.

Comment: first i select car price 100. its shows all the result from under 100 price, then select category low, then we will get under 100 & low category cars.... Then again i select car price 50 its shows car price under 50, not considering prev set price category low

Comment: Now that needs us to see CarResult Component. but I understood that your `category` is reset every time you set a `price`. just check your `priceHandler` and set the `category` there too

Comment: i cant follow you , i am newbie in react, so please provide me a article or  code :(

Comment: No problem if you are a newbie. I welcome you. Show me your state object. since in your handleChange you are just overwriting the object. Can you create a CodePen or CodeSandBox?

Comment: sure, sir please give 2 min

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196024/discussion-between-its4zahoor-and-harry-edward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/multiple-filters-on-items-using-react-h9rck) for setting up multiple filters on items in react list. Created to answer this question after the [Discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/196024).

**Tips for similar problems**

1. Keep your `list/array` and `filter variables` in the parent component
2. Filter the list in `render(){}`, don't `setState` just pass as prop to child component
3. Pass `this.HandleChange` as prop

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific with your question?

As per my understanding, looks like its working as you have programmed it. If you have already set category state to high and only changing price to 1000 then its should show all cars from category high under 1000.

If you don't want that to happen you have to reset category state each time you change the price

Comment: first i select car price 100. its shows all the result from under 100 price, then select category low, then we will get under 100 & low category cars.... Then again i select car price 50 its shows car price under 50, not considering prev set price category low

Comment: Check the state of your react component when you are changing it. You can check with react-dev-tools in chrome browser, or can log the state in render and change method after it gets change.

Check if it is updating both of the states. As per your code it should update one state whichever is changed.

Also check your filter function if it is in parent component you are only providing the latest change state and not both of your states. If in the same component, you can always add console to check the states getting passed.

Comment: i cant follow you , i am newbie in react, so please provide me a article or code :(